# GWT GIN: Can Gijector return generic of unknown type?

Tags: java, generics, gwt, inject, gwt-gin

Im developing webapp using GWT and GIN, I'm really curious if its possible to use Ginjector to return generic type, but unknown for implementation untill usage?

maybe code will clear my question:

My Gin module:

```
@GinModules(GinModule.class)
public interface ShowcaseInjector extends Ginjector {
    <T> ValuePickerQuestionComposite<T> getValuePickerQuestion();
}
```

Class to be injected

```
public class ValuePickerQuestionComposite<T>{
    //some implementation with T required

}
```

Usage of gin:

```
ShowcaseInjector injector = GWT.create(ShowcaseInjector.class);
ValuePickerQuestionComposite<Integer> instance = injector.getValuePickerQuestion();
```

I may need implemenation for Integer, String, Double, because of generic widget inside.
From my research I found some bindings, but for them Ginjector knows exactly what type generic is, so its something like

```
ValuePickerQuestionComposite<Integer> getValuePickerQuestion();
```

But I want it to be unknown untill usage.
Is my idea even possible? If is, could somebody point what type of configuration should I use?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Everything has to be known at compile-time via static analysis, so no it won't work.

Moreover, the way Java implements generics, the method being called would never know which type argument is being used; the type parameter here is only for type-safety (sort of) to avoid a cast.

Comment: What if I know what I need in compile time: on example I'm sure, I'd like to have instance for Integers, can I somehow pass Integer.class to let module know what type this is?